# Determine in Angular whether a 'change in value for a component' is a result of a detected change

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

We're using the 'switch' component of DevExtreme and have set the `onValueChanged` event of that component to execute some action.

However, this is also triggered when the property value of the bound object is changed (as a result of updating the underlying data).

But we only want to perform the action, when the user changes the switch value.

So how can I detect whether the change is a result of a ChangeDetection update?

Html-code:

```html
<dx-form [formData]="myobject" [colCount]="6">
  <dxi-item dataField="myobjectprop" editorType="dxSwitch" [editorOptions]="{ value:myobject.myobjectprop, onValueChanged:someaction }" cssClass="switch-right-label">
    <dxo-label text="my property" location="right" alignment="left">
    </dxo-label>
  </dxi-item>
</dx-form>
```

ts-code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-my-object',
  templateUrl: './test-my-object.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-my-object.component.scss']
})
export class TestMyObjectComponent implements OnInit {

  myobject: MyObject;
  onObjectChanged: BehaviorSubject<MyObject>;

  constructor() { 
    this.onObjectChanged = new BehaviorSubject(new MyObject());
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onObjectChanged
      .subscribe(newmyobject => {
        this.myobject = newmyobject;
      });
  }

  someaction = (): Promise<boolean> => {
    // Do something when the data changed
    // - but not when change is a result of using using 'changeObject' <= how to know that???
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /*...*/ });
  }

  changeObject(): void {
    const obj = new MyObject();
    obj.myobjectprop = !this.myobject.myobjectprop;
    this.onObjectChanged.next(obj);
  }  
}

export class MyObject {
  myobjectprop: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution (at least when using the DevExteme components).

Basically one needs to check, whether the `event` property of the eventobject passed thought the event handler, is set (or not).

Example:

```
someaction = (e): Promise<boolean> => {
  if (e.event === undefined) {
    // event was triggered by code
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /*...*/ });
}
```